# in Djando view class getting error - global name 'self' is not defined

Tags: django, class, self

In my Django based app

I am trying to override delete method of Delete view.
I have 2 Models `Category` and `Subcategory`.

Category is Foreign key of subcategory and it is protected on delete .

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

This is my class in view.py 
However each time I execute I am getting -  global name 'self' is not defined.

(the code is inside the class so self should be referring to the class. I thought I have to create instance to use it but all samples I saw online on Django do it exactly like this.)

```
class CategoryDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Category
    success_url = reverse_lazy('category_list')

    def delete(request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if self.object.gameteams_set.exists():
            # Return the appropriate response
            success_url = self.get_success_url()
            self.object.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function argument is missing `self`:

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

`delete` function belongs to class `CategoryDelete`, so class methods needs `self` to access properties of the instance.